# How to convert 12 hr date time format to 24 hr format using java script?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am sending the data from my database as 24 hr format, but when i use it on front-end for time counter as below the output gives 'none'.
Also,When I print the 'plan_deactive_date' it shows time in 12 hr format.
So, is there any way to convert the datetime from 12 hr format to 24 hr format?

```html
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to

var countDownDate = new Date("{{plan_deactive_date}}").getTime();


// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Expired";
  }
}, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the snippet, add the `#demo` element to the HTML section, and replace the Django placehodler with a real value.

Comment: _“Also,When I print the 'plan_deactive_date' it shows time in 12 hr format.”_ - well that’s probably the actual cause of your problem already … If JS can’t parse that format, then of course the whole script will fail. So this should be fixed on the server side - by outputting the date in a format that JS _can_ parse in the first place - and not “retroactively” fumbled into something workable on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
```

Read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. To get date in *24* hour format

   - `data.toLocaleString('en-GB')`
2. To get date in *12* hour format

   - `data.toLocaleString('en')`